# Minimize the sequence by putting appropriate operations ' DP'

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a sequence,say,
222
We have to put a '+' or '* ' between each adjacent pair.
'* ' has higher precedence over '+'

We have to o/p the string whose evaluation leads to minimum value.
O/p must be lexicographically smallest if there are more than one.

inp:222

o/p: 2*2+2

Explaination:

2+2+2=6

2+2*2=6

2*2+2=6

of this 3rd is lexicographically smallest.

I was wondering how to construct a DP solution for this.

Comment: What are your numbers? integers, naturals, reals, what? How many can you have max? If this is from an online judge, can you please post a link to it?

Comment: since we have to put an operation between each adjacent pair,
It can only be 0-9. Also each are integers.
and the maximum length of input is 100, means 100 digits.
Yeah, this is from an OJ, But m not able to find the question now.

Comment: Hm. This would be easy if you didn't have to take precedence into account...

Comment: @sepp2k
No, we have to take precedence into account.

Comment: @Vikas: I know, that's why I said *would*

Comment: Ok, here's an idea. Not posting it as an answer yet because I'm not sure (@sepp2k - this one covers that too :)): If you have a `0` in your string, use `*` everywhere - this is obvious.

If you have a 1, make use of the fact that `1 + x > 1*x for every natural x`, so put a `*` before or after the 1. It doesn't matter where you put it.

Put `+` everywhere else. Anyone see a problem with this? Still working out the details of it being lexicographically smallest, although I think that's a simple matter of replacing the `+` with `*` if that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @IVlad: For 121 you should insert `*` everywhere, but your logic will insert one `+` (because you're not allowing to put a `*` on both sides of the 1, which is correct in most other cases).

Comment: @Ivlad
Yeah there is a problem in this.
I got the problem.
Here is copy of problem with some Example test-cases.
http://pastebin.com/q9edMT77
i am not giving the exact-link because one needs an account to view the problem.

@IVlad: Your algo will fail on 4th example case.Plz have a look.

Comment: Ok, what if we put a `*` near every digit that has an adjacent 1? That looks like it would pass all the test cases.

Comment: @IVlad: 13131. You need one `+` to get to 6, but your revised logic will only add `*`s.

Comment: @Ivlad.
There is a solution other than DP.
but I am  looking for a 'DP approach' to solve the same.
That's Why I mentioned DP exclusively in this problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `DP[N]` be the smallest value we can obtain using the first `N` elements. I will do a recursive implementation(using memoization) with pseudocode:

```
int solve(int index)
{
   if (index == N)
      return 0;

   if (DP[index] already computed) 
      return DP[index];

   int result = INFINITELY LARGE NUMBER;

   //put a + sign
   result = min(result, input[index] + solve(index + 1));

   //put consecutive * signs
   int cur = input[index];
   for (int i = index + 1; i < N; i++)
   {
       cur *= input[i];
       result = min(result, cur + solve(i + 1));          
   }

   return DP[index] = result;
}
```

Call it with `solve(0);`

You can easily reconstruct the solution after this. I haven't tested it and maybe I have missed an edge case in the pseudocode but it should give you the right track.

```
string reconstruct(int index)
{
    if (index == N)
       return "";

    string result = "";

    //put consecutive * signs
    int cur = input[index]; 
    string temp = ToString(input[index]);
    for (int i = index + 1; i < N; i++)
    {           
        cur *= input[i];
        temp += "*";

        if (DP[index] == cur + DP[i + 1])
           result = temp + reconstruct(i + 1);
    }

    //put a + sign
    if (result == "") 
       result = ToString(input[index]) + "+" + reconstruct(index + 1);

    return result;
}

string result = reconstruct(0);
```

P.S Sorry for the many edits.

Comment: Can you explain Why you went for consecutive '*' sign?(for loop)

Comment: Because the previous solution was not correct. I didn't take in account properly the precedence of *.

Comment: And the solution now is much easier to understand:)

Comment: Can you tell how to reconstruct solution?